# I want to create a random integer with javascript

Tags: javascript

Ive used math.random() to create a random number, but i want it to be an integer and not have any decimal places heres what ive got for it:

```
var RandomNumber = function RandomNumber13() {
return Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/) method :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
return Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1;
```

to

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

in order to have random integer between 1 to 3.

---

Update:

For generating random number among 1, 2 or 3, you can also use this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3];
return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I also wanted it to generate between 1 and 3, so what have i done wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with `floor()`

```
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min and max
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

> **Floor : Round a number downward to its nearest integer**

Source from [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: remember to provide source if you copy from somewhere.